# Facebook posting

Tags: ios, facebook

here is what I did

- Created an app on facebook
- installed the FB SDK with all the requirements
- logged in the user via a login button
- now I am trying to post with the code provided here from this threat 
  [How to Post to Facebook on iOS 6 in Objective-C using ACAccountStore class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12505458/how-to-post-to-facebook-on-ios-6-in-objective-c-using-acaccountstore-class)

But nothing happens. Am I missing a step?

This is the code I am using

```
 if([SLComposeViewController isAvailableForServiceType:SLServiceTypeFacebook]) //check if Facebook Account is linked
    {
      mySLComposerSheet = [[SLComposeViewController alloc] init]; //initiate the Social Controller
        mySLComposerSheet = [SLComposeViewController composeViewControllerForServiceType:SLServiceTypeFacebook]; //Tell him with what social plattform to use it, e.g. facebook or twitter
                [mySLComposerSheet setInitialText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Test",mySLComposerSheet.serviceType]]; //the message you want to post
       [mySLComposerSheet addImage:yourimage]; //an image you could post
        //for more instance methodes, go here:https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Reference/SLComposeViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012205
        [self presentViewController:mySLComposerSheet animated:YES completion:nil];
    }
    [mySLComposerSheet setCompletionHandler:^(SLComposeViewControllerResult result) {
        NSString *output;
        switch (result) {
            case SLComposeViewControllerResultCancelled:
                output = @"Action Cancelled";
                break;
            case SLComposeViewControllerResultDone:
                output = @"Post Successfull";
                break;
            default:
                break;
        } //check if everything worked properly. Give out a message on the state.
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Facebook" message:output delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alert show];
    }];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `setInitialText` method is incorrect.
If you use `stringWithFormat` to post the serviceType, you need to add it to the method with "%@", otherwise there isn't anything there to say it to appear.

In short, just change :

```
[mySLComposerSheet setInitialText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Test",mySLComposerSheet.serviceType]];
```

to :

```
[mySLComposerSheet setInitialText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Test %@",mySLComposerSheet.serviceType]];
```