# Posting on Facebook - Follow up questions

Tags: objective-c, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I've seen [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12505458/how-to-post-to-facebook-on-ios-6-in-objective-c-using-acaccountstore-class) on SO for "how to post on Facebook?", 
my question is composed of 3 followups

1. How can I set the page/group on which the post will show (other than my wall?
2. Is there a way to post without being logged in?
3. Sending a private message to one of my friends - possible & how?

Answer (score -1):

According to your question... if i understand you good, android application Hoot Suite will do the job...
And no you can't post to facebook if you are not logged in to any account

Comment: didn't understand your answer please elaborate, also notice I'm developing an iphone application