# Posting to Facebook iOS 6-8

Tags: ios, xcode, facebook, frameworks

I'm having problems getting my application to post to Facebook...

I have twitter posting fine. But when I try posting to Facebook it freezes/is unresponsive...

Originally I followed [AppCoda's](http://www.appcoda.com/ios-programming-101-integrate-twitter-and-facebook-sharing-in-ios-6/) tutorial. Twitter works, but Facebook's implementation doesn't...

Then I changed to code to GeekyLemons tutorial:

```
//mySLComposerSheet = [[SLComposeServiceViewController alloc] init];
mySLComposerSheet = [SLComposeViewController composeViewControllerForServiceType:SLServiceTypeFacebook];
[mySLComposerSheet setInitialText:@"Place Text Here"];
[self presentViewController:mySLComposerSheet animated:YES completion:nil];
```

But that doesn't work...

Then I tried all the example answers give on [THIS ANSWER](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12505458/how-to-post-to-facebook-on-ios-6-in-objective-c-using-acaccountstore-class) here on the exchange, still nothing.

Then I tried using the Twitter code and changing it to Facebook to keep it basic:

```
SLComposeViewController *fbSheet = [SLComposeViewController composeViewControllerForServiceType:SLServiceTypeFacebook];
[fbSheet setInitialText:@"So... I just posted from my App :)"];
[self presentViewController:fbSheet animated: YES completion: nil];
```

Same thing...

When the `IBAction` is called/the `PostToFacebook` button in pressed, it brings up the little text window, but DOESN'T have the text inside of it thats pre written in the code above. Then when I type something (because the text that should appear, doesn't) and press post, the window closes and the app freezes... :(

I don't know what else to try... I'm completely stumped. I don't see why all of the tutorials/examples have the same issue... None place the text in the window, and after pressing post, it freezes.

It's worth mentioning that I have Facebook set up on my device, just like twitter... Twitter works, but Facebook doesn't.

Is there anything else I can try? Or am I being really stupid and missing something.? Thank you.

**Update**

I started a brand new project incase my application was doing something strange, but unfortunately when I run it, it still isn't working :(

**ViewController.h:**

```
 #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
 #import <Social/Social.h>
 #import <Accounts/Accounts.h>

 @interface ViewController : UIViewController{
     SLComposeViewController *mySLComposerSheet;
 }

 -(IBAction)PostToFacebook:(id)sender;

 @end
```

**ViewController.m**

```
 #import "ViewController.h"

 @interface ViewController ()

 @end

 @implementation ViewController

 -(IBAction)PostToFacebook:(id)sender{
     NSLog(@"PostToFacebook Button Pressed...");
         mySLComposerSheet = [[SLComposeViewController alloc] init];
     NSLog(@"Allocated Memory......");
         mySLComposerSheet = [SLComposeViewController composeViewControllerForServiceType:SLServiceTypeFacebook];
     NSLog(@"Composed Service...");
         [mySLComposerSheet setInitialText:@"Hello World"];
     NSLog(@"Set Text...%@", mySLComposerSheet);
         [self presentViewController:mySLComposerSheet animated:YES completion:nil];
     NSLog(@"Presenting ViewController...");
 }

 - (void)viewDidLoad {
     [super viewDidLoad];
     // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
     NSLog(@"ViewDidLoad...");
 }

 - (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
     [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
     // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
 }

 @end
```

And I've linked up the "PostToFacebook" button in the Storyboard... using `Touch Up Inside`... Still nothing :(

**Another Update**

So I've just tested it on the `iOS Simulator` and it works after signing into Facebook in the simulators settings... But it's still not working on my iPhone 6+ device... even though Twitter does...?!?!